# Variable not updating in lambda slot

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda

I need to run a function with arguments (`Installer::install`) on a `QProcess::finished` signal. I've decided to use a lambda as slot, resulting in this:

```
private:
    QProcess* unzip = new QProcess(this);`
```

```
void Installer::extract(QString source, QString destination) {
    QStringList args;
    args.append("x");
    args.append(source);
    args.append(QString("-o%1").arg(destination));
    connect(unzip, &QProcess::finished, this, [=](int code, QProcess::ExitStatus status) {
        if (code != 0 || status == QProcess::CrashExit) {
            qDebug() << "Installer - Error >> Exit code:" << code;
            qDebug() << "Installer - Error >> Status:" << status;
            emit error();
        }
        else
            install(destination + "/game.exe");
        });
    unzip->start("path\to\extractor\program.exe", args);
    if (!unzip->waitForStarted()) {
        qDebug() << "Installer - Error >> Extractor not started";
        qDebug() << "Installer - Error Detail >>" << unzip->error();
        emit error();
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << "Sot Installer - Updates - Extractor >> Extracting...";
}
```

`Installer::extract` function is called at the end of every extraction. Supposing we have four archives to extract, `Installer::extract` will be called four times, with four different `destination`.

For the first archive, all works well. From the second one, the `destination` variable inside the lambda slot has the value of the first `destination` while it should have the second `destination` value. Instead, the `destination` variable outside the slot (e.g. in the last `args.append`) has the right value. Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: It seems like the problem is outside of the code that you have provided, please share the code that runs the `Installer::extract` function.

Comment: It seems you are connecting all signal to the same `unzip` instance. Every time `extract` is called, you connect an additional slot to the same signal. When `QProcess::finished` fires, all slots are executed one after the other, not just the last one as you appear to expect. The slot connected the earlies - the one with the first `destination` - will always be the first to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Igor Tandetnik, connections were stacking up and so were the values of destination. Disconnecting all the connections of unzip before running `Installer::extract` again solved the problem.